# ERROR: pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, module, python-wheel, install.packages, pyhook

I am trying to make a keylogger in Python that requires pyHook module. I tried `pip install pyHook` but it did not work.

So, I downloaded this package from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/ -

*pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl*

Then I tried to install it using:

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

But is shows the error given in heading.

I even downloaded this package from same site - *pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl*

But none of them works. So what should I do? Please help.

My system is `64-bit` and I use `Python 3.8`.

Comment: "*I use Python 3.8*" Then why have you downloaded a wheel for Python 3.7? `cp37` means "CPython 3.7".

Comment: `Python 3.8` is very new version - it can be better to use Python 3.7

Comment: @phd   it is not available for python 3.8

Comment: @furas   Will it work with python 3.7 ?

Comment: `cp37` means that it is for Python 3.7, not for 3.8, but I would uses `pip install pyHook` and it should download version for your Python (if exists). If you get error with `pip install pyHook` then you could describe it.

Comment: With pip install pyhook, I get the following error - 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyHook

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are using python 3.8, and you need to install python 3.7 to run the pyhook library.

Try to uninstall your version 38 then install python 3.74, and finally run your command

```
pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp**37**-cp**37**m-win_amd64.whl
```